# TABLE_QUERY fails to handle dataset names starting with numbers

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a dataset that starts with a number. When referenced in TABLE_QUERY, it results in the following error:

```
select count(*) from  (TABLE_QUERY([3abc]  , 'table_id in ("delivered_201508")'))
```

error raised:

```
Error: Encountered "" at line 1, column 36.
```

Surrounding the dataset reference with brackets makes the query work:

```
select count(*) from  (TABLE_QUERY([3abc]  , 'table_id in ("delivered_201508")'))
```

Bracket-less references to datasets that do not start with numbers work ok. Is this expected behavior or a bug in the SQL parser?

Comment: the first query should be select count(*) from  (TABLE_QUERY(3abc  , 'table_id in ("delivered_201508")'))

Comment: This is expected behavior and the brackets in BigQuery means escaping/enclosing and it's recommended to be used on all known identifiers.

Comment: I see now it's asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462891/bigquery-dataset-name-starting-with-a-number-and-table-date-range.